# javascript DOM difference between children & lastElementChild

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question with my assignment, it doesn't work when I want to delete the item.

But when I change a little bit, it does work. I assume that they are indicated to the same node. But why?

```
  const target = event.target
  const point = target.parentElement.children[2]
  // const point = target.parentElement.lastElementChild ///// it works when I change to this.
  let pointValue = Number(point.innerText)
  const list = target.parentElement.parentElement
  if (target.matches('.fa-thumbs-up')){
    pointValue ++
    point.innerText = pointValue
  } else if (target.matches('.fa-thumbs-down')){
    pointValue --
    point.innerText = pointValue
  } else if (target.matches('.btn-danger')){
    console.log(target)
    list.remove()
  } 
})
```

here's my codepen:
https://codepen.io/lgtits/pen/yLXQpqy?editors=0111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check if 'lastElementChild' of the parent is really children[2] or not. Otherwise it should work.

Comment: yes, I add point2 and check they are the same.

Comment: Check for 'children' only ( like use this in console - `target.parentElement.children`, (not children[2]) and see what list does this returns, in that list(or array), see what is the index of the element(or node) that you want to reach.

Comment: I found the problem, thanks!

Comment: I am very glad that I was able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you access it with `children` it return **Array of HTML Collection**. And `children` is property that returns that array, it is not an array itself.

```
const myElements = target.parentElement.children[2] // Doesn't work
// 'list' is type of Array
const point = target.parentElement.lastElementChild; // Works (This directly return the last element)
const point = myElements[2]; // This will also works
```

Comment: could you tell more please, I add coneole.log(typeof(point)) and found that they are the same. I still not get it.